# How do I separate a specific sequence from a string multiple times?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a string named protein. It prints something like this: `KALSKJKDALIEUTSTARTALKSJDALK*KAJSLDKJSTARTJAISOIEWORUNCD*`

I want a code that will search this string for `START` and `*` and print the characters in between them, in this case letters.

For example: `protein = STARTJSADHFJAS*KJSTARTAKSLJDIOQWIE*`

`print protein_filtered = [JSADHFJAS, AKSLJDIOQWIE]`

So far I have this, but this will only get me the first protein sequence. Also, I don't care if its appended to a list or if its a string.

```
start_marker = 'START'
end_marker = '*'
start = protein.index(start_marker) + len(start_marker)
end = protein.index(end_marker, start + 1)
print protein[start:end]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
START(.*?)\*
```

You can do this through `re`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hE4jH0/41

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'START(.*?)\*', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = u"STARTJSADHFJAS*KJSTARTAKSLJDIOQWIE*"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

We have used `non greedy regex` here by appending `?` after `.*` .That is so that the regex stops on the first occurrence of `*`.If it is greedy it will reach up to the last occurrence of `*`

Comment: Here you have my up-vote, but please provide more details about your regex. Greedy? Lazy? Let him know what this is about.

Comment: Thank you, vks. This answer is perfect!

Comment: @PeterSamuel do accept by clicking the green arrow.

Answer (score 0):

One Solution can be:

```
final_list = [i.split('\\')[0] for i in [i for i protein.split('START') if i]]
```